# How to download a pdf which has restrictions

Tags: pdf, read-only, print-to-pdf, restrictions

Here is the link https://app.box.com/embed/s/2297cfgv15po5ycuggpba2oh42p5mutw

The above page shows a pdf inside a `div` tag and then `canvas` html tag.

I tried to following ways:

- Download the pdf by printing but it doesn't appear in print dialog too.
- The developer tool doesn't shows link to any ".pdf" file.
- Also tries to check the 'Page Info' dialog in firefox, but it didn't showed any *.pdf file, or the current pdf in jpg format.
  [Page Info dialog in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWec4.png)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What happens if you log in to an account with that app? As far as I can tell trial or basic accounts are free, so if you don't have an account you should be able to just get one. I can't see an obvious way to download the file otherwise, although there may be a way.

Comment: I'm thinking there may be some menu options available to you if you're logged in that you don't currently have access to, and they may give you an easy way to download.

Comment: This is a proprietary viewer run from the site. They don't want you downloading the content. While I feel your pain, the short answer is that you shouldn't download it. Circumventing the protections would be a violation of the law, and in most cases it would just be easier to set up an account on the site and access it directly from the provider.

Comment: Even login doesn't help here, after login same page appears but with a logout button in header that's it.